# UICollectionView *Assertion Failure* for not applying attributes on UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, nib

I am trying to do the following:

A)Level 1 is unlocked (contains background image for unlocked levels).

B)Level 2-20 are locked (contains another background image). They will be unlocked as each successive level is complete.

Initially when I run the app, and go to my `UICollectionView`, everything looks good.  When I play level 1, and complete it, I save (through Core Data) the number 0 for an `NSNumber` managed object called `levelLocked`, belonging now to level 2 (0 means unlocked, and the other levels 3-20 should be locked with a 1).

That process of saving whether a level is locked or unlocked works.  But when I return to my `UICollectionView`, I do not see the physical change for level 2 (it still has the background image of the lock).

Furthermore, if I return to the `ViewController` before the `UICollectionView`, then re-enter the `UICollectionView`, the app crashes with the error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:],
```

It appears my cell is not being updated properly (I do not know how to reload data properly).  I did register the custom `UICollectionViewCell` nib for both unlocked and locked level types.  I checked all spelling (it wouldn't have worked the first time around to begin with if that was the issue).

Here's the code for the cell generation.

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"tortoiseCell";
static NSString *tortIdentifier = @"tortoiseLocked";

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
             cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionViewCell *regular;

    NSMutableArray *data = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSString *cellData = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSMutableArray *ar = [self.lockArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSNumber *arLocks = [ar objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([arLocks integerValue] == 0) {

        TortoiseCell *cell = (TortoiseCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell.buttonClick setTag:indexPath.row];
        [cell.buttonClick setTitle:cellData forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.buttonClick setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TortoiseLevels.png"]
                                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.buttonClick addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedSoWhatNumber:)
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.buttonClick.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        [cell addSubview:cell.buttonClick];
        cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
        cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        regular = cell;

    } else if ([arLocks integerValue] == 1) {

        TortoiseLocked *lockCell = (TortoiseLocked *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:tortIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [lockCell.tortoiseLock setTag:indexPath.row];
        [lockCell.tortoiseLock setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TortoiseLock.png"]
                                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        lockCell.tortoiseLock.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        [lockCell addSubview:lockCell.tortoiseLock];
        lockCell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
        lockCell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        regular = lockCell;
    }   
    return regular;
}
```

Let me know what you think.  I'm using iOS 8.1 with XCode 7.1.2

Comment: Is there any more text for the exception?  There should be a reason or explanation as to why the assertion failed

Comment: Like I mentioned in the other posts, this is the full assertion failure message: `Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:]`

Comment: A couple of things jump out at me straight away. First, you are adding subviews to the cell, but in the case where a cell is reused you will be adding additional subviews. These subviews should be part of your cell subclass and you shouldn't need to add them here. Second, using the tag to capture the index is fragile. It is better to implement a protocol between the cell and the controlller so that a delegate method is called when the cell button is tapped. The delegate method receives the cell and then you can use `indexPathForCell` to retrieve the indexPath.

Comment: The most popular answer to fix this is to register the nib with a reuse identifier.  I have already done that.

Comment: Finally, and this could be your problem, it is possible for this code to return `nil`. Since you test explicitly for 0 and 1, any other value will result in `nil` which will give you an exception. Change the `else if` to a simple `else` and see what happens

Comment: The first two issues I pointed out aren't really anything to do with nib regsitration, except that if you register a nib then the subviews you are adding will be part of the nib and you won't need that code here, which is what I am saying

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through this code to see what happens prior to the exception?

Comment: How would I be able to remove the original subviews?  Or, better yet, when the cell information changes, how do I not reuse a cell (unless that's not how it works).   I'm very new to this, my bad if my questions aren't well-formed.

Comment: The `if-else` statement is comparing 0 and 1 based on Core Data values I fetch to determine if a level was completed or not.  I wrote it as such because I will only ever be comparing 0 or 1.  Unless that's not a guarantee 100% of the time

Comment: I add a breakpoint when the assertion failure is thrown, and I can't seem to track it down.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126660/discussion-between-paulw11-and-anthony-the-kid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` can return `nil` if the value in your array is neither 0 or 1. I suspect that this is what is happening, and then the collection view has an assertion failure, since you have given it nil instead of a cell.

The simple fix is to change the `else if` to `else` and this will result in a "locked" cell by default.

You could also add a new `else` clause that logs an error and use that to try and diagnose why you aren't getting 0/1.

Comment: Thanks again, the assertion failure is gone, and the app no longer crashes.  I have to touch up some things with Core Data to make sure all levels unlocked appear as number strings instead of just the current unlocked level.